# Disable logger during junit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, mocking

Is it possible to disable the execution of the logger during testing?

I have this class

```
public class UnitTestMe {

    private final MockMe mockMe;
    private final SomethingElse something;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getClass());

    public UnitTestMe(MockMe mockMe, SomethingElse something) {
        this..
    }

    public toTest() {
        logger.info("Executing toTest. MockMe a: {}, Foo: b: {}", mockMe.toString(), something.foo().bar());
        mockMe.execute();
    }
}
```

My Unit Test is failing with an NullPointerException because something.foo() is not a mocked object (i am using mockito with nicemock).

How can I test this class without removing the logger statement and without mocking irrelevant parts of the dependencies like `something`?

**Edit:** something is in this case a Customer Object, that is not used in the `toTest()` function but needed in other parts of this Class. I am using the Customer class in the logger statement to relate an action to an user.

**Edit 2:** Would it help to mock the logger object? I would assume that I will get an `NullPointerException` again, because the methods of the `something´ object are executed, too.

Comment: can't you just surround it with `try...catch (NullPointerException)` ?

Comment: Never, **ever**, catch `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Poor answer**: first decrease logging level to `WARN` or `ERROR` for this logger. Then, surround logging statement with `isInfoEnabled()`:

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled())
    logger.info("Executing toTest. MockMe a: {}, Foo: b: {}", mockMe.toString(), something.foo().bar());
```

---

**Better one**: it looks a bit weird that you are using some object only for logging, so when you are testing a `toTest()` method, mocked dependency is used only for logging. I understand this is just an example, but looks like there is some design flaw. I would suggest mocking `SomethingElse` for the sake of simplicity as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your logging statement introduce an additional requirement for the mocking of `something`.  You must make it give a non-null value returned for foo(), or rewrite your logging statements to avoid introducing these extra things.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the execution of logger

#### usecase for PowerMockito:

```
// this is to suppress for logger.error(Exception e)
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(logger, "error", (Exception) any(Exception.class));

// this is to suppress for logger.debug(String message)
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(logger, "debug",anyString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try catch NullPointerException`.

If your test method want to test NullPointerException it will be better us expect NullPointerException

```
@expect(NullPointerException.class)
public void testMethod() {
//your test method logic
}
```